# Firebase console : Project Settings option not showing tabs for "General", "Cloud Messaging", "Analytics" when logged in from safari (v 9.1.2)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to configure the push notification service in my xamarin.android project. But when I logged in to firebase console I am not able to see the project settings option tabs for "General", "Cloud Messaging", "Analytics" when I logged in from safari.

[image]

I need the sender id and server key to configure push notification from my server side code. Which is normally found like this :

[image]

Comment: Console works fine on my end. I suggest reaching out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) directly for this.

Comment: I am facing this problem in safari, when I logged in from chrome, it is working fine. It's surprising, wasted 1 hr due to this.

Comment: I have reported this issue to "Firebase Support"